# How to make a sprite above my character appear on the minimap attached to the floor?

Tags: sprites, unreal-4, blueprints, minimap

I have a project where I made 2 minimaps.

**One of minimaps is linked to the character of my project and the other to the floor:**

[image]

As I already said in the title of the question, my character has a sprite above the head (red arrow) that appears on the minimap attached to it, but does not appear on the minimap attached to the floor.

**Image:**

[image]

I looked at the rendering options and many others, but I could not get the sprite to show up. How do I get the sprite to appear on the floor minimap?

---

**EDIT 1 (Showing how I made the minimap)**

**I used a SpringArm:**

[image]

**And a SceneCaptureComponent2D:**

[image]

**The PaperSprite is not the children of the SpringArm and stands a little below the SceneCaptureComponent2D:**

[image]

**The minimap is made from a RenderTarget. From this RenderTarget a material is created:**

[image]

**Widget Blueprint:**

[image]

Comment: And how did you make a minimap ? Is it a render target ? Umg ? AHud ? Something else ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought there was only one way to make a minimap. I already put it like I did in the question.

Comment: Without any pretense the problem was solved, but without explanation. I simply had to increase the size of the floor. With this the minimap failed to capture its full extent, so I had to increase the "Ortho Width" option. The sprite began to appear. I reversed the size for the initial and the sprite continued to appear. Apparently it was a bug.